# Exponential of presheaves

Tags: category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

> Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a small category, and $Y$, $Z$ presheaves on $\mathbb{C}$. We showed in class that if an exponential $Z^Y$ exists in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, then it must be given by the formula
> \begin{equation}
>   Z^Y(c) \cong \hat{\mathbb{C}}(y(c) \times Y, Z)
> \end{equation}
> for each $c \in \mathbb{C}$, where $y$ is the yoneda embedding. Work this out carefully, that is,
>
> (a) describe fully the functor $\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Set}$ whose action on objects is given by the above formula, and
>
> (b) show that it does indeed give an exponential for $Y$ and $Z$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

This is a question from an old class at my university that I am now independently studying, but did not attend the lectures, and we are working out of Awodey. I understand the basic notion of presheaves and exponentials, and I feel like I could tackle part (b) of this problem, but I am stumped on part (a). First of all, I do not understand what
\begin{equation}
  Z^Y(c) \cong \hat{\mathbb{C}}(y(c) \times Y, Z)
\end{equation}
means… I thought $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathrm{Set}^{\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}$, the functor category of presheaves. So I don’t understand the terminology being used here when it seems to use $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ as a function.

Can someone give me a good way of approaching this problem and perhaps a bit more insight on the motivation behind the problem? I know its a vague question, but I appreciate whatever I can get!

Comment: It is common in textbook to write $\mathcal A(a,b)$ for the set of morphisms between $a$ and $b$ in the category $\mathcal A$. You might be more familiar with the notation $\hom(a,b)$ or $\hom_{\mathcal A}(a,b)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use brackets for the $\hom$-sets, to simplify notation. $E,Y$ and $Z$ are presheaves on the category $C$. For the intuition of this, note the following: for arbitrary $c\in C,$ we have, by Yoneda, a natural bijection $\tag 1 [yc, Z^Y]\cong Z^Yc.$

Furthermore, if an exponential object exists, then owing to the exponential/product adjunction, we must have $\tag 2[E \times Y, Z] \cong [E, Z^Y].$ Setting $E=yc$ we have now $\tag 3[yc \times Y, Z] \cong [yc, Z^Y].$

Now, combine $(1)$ and $(3)$ to obtain your result.

Of course, you need to show that this assignment actually defines an exponential object.

Answer (score 1):

When $\mathcal{C}$ is a category, this is one of the common notations for the "hom-set"; that is, in five different notation styles,

$$ \mathcal{C}(x, y) = \hom(x, y) = \hom_{\mathcal{C}}(x, y) = [x,y] = [x,y]_{\mathcal{C}}$$

All three, of course, are notation for the values of a *functor* $\mathcal{C}^\circ \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$, so the same formula apples when $x,y$ are objects, arrows, or a mix of the two.

---

As for motivation, exponentials are important, so we want to be able to compute them! And it turns out we can do so by combining two of our basic facts:

$$ Z^Y(c) \cong \hat{\mathcal{C}}(y(c), Z^Y) \cong \hat{\mathcal{C}}(y(c) \times Y, Z) $$

This formula is functoral in all three variables, expressing the values of isomorphic functors $\mathcal{C}^\circ \times \hat{\mathcal{C}}^\circ \times \hat{\mathcal{C}}$, so $c$ can either be an object or arrow of $\mathcal{C}$, and $Y,Z$ can each either be presheaves or morphisms of presheaves. Although, this problem is only asking you to work through the isomorphisms for a fixed $Y,Z$.

Being able to plug in an arrow $f : c \to d$ and work through the calculation to get an explicit formula for how $Z^Y(f)$ acts to relate $Z^Y(c)$ and $Z^Y(d)$ is a good exercise to help one become comfortable with all of the relevant basics.

Comment: This is great !